# Re-activate Visual Studio Smart Tags?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I saw a solution to this question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465997/where-is-smart-tag-button-in-visual-studio-2015/57564890#57564890. However, I was referred here to ask my question. I tried the 2 solutions there, but with no success? My solution was to repair the VS2015 installation, but that takes a long time for such a small issue! Especially because they soon disappear again?!

Smart tags are a very convenient way of adding standard items to controls, but my question is why do the smart tags keep disappearing (i.e. use of keyboard shortcuts or something?). Is there a solution to turn them back on rather than repairing the VS installation? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have in *Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer* the option of "Automatically Open Smart Tags" set to "True"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion harrymc! Actually, if you look back at the solution I gave the link for, that is one of the suggestions. To answer you question, yes that option is set to true. I also tried the other suggestion which didn't work either. Repairing the VS2015 installation works and I now have the smart tags back. But, that is a long way round for restoring smart tags that keep disappearing! This is a common problem, but I would like to know what causes it and a better plus quicker solution than mine!